# For loop of 'Insert into' sql-statement not working in c#

Tags: c#, sql

In C#, I have a method to insert an array of string values into a sql db. It looks something like this

```
void ProcessRow(string[] row)
{
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        var myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO mytable bla bla bla using content of row"), myConnection);
        myCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The method `ProcessRow(string[] row)` is being called in a for loop to insert multiple different rows. However, when the code gets executed, nothing has been added to mytable. When I make `ProcessRow(string[] row)` wait a bit after each insert, as follows

```
void ProcessRow(string[] row)
{
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        var myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO mytable bla bla bla using content of row"), myConnection);
        myCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

then everything works fine and my rows get added to mytable.

My question is: what is going wrong in the first approach, without adding the sleep(100)? It feels like there is some kind of concurrency problem, but I don't see how this is possible since each insert is contained in a using() {}.

Comment: `BeginExecuteNonQuery()` causes an async operation to start. You probably can't do anything with that same connection (e.g. another insert) until that async op completes. You either need wait until it has completed, and continue your work then, or switch to a synchronous method, like `ExecuteNonQuery()`. See [this MSDN article for an example.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `BeginExecuteNonQuery`? `Initiates the asynchronous execution of the Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure that is described by this SqlCommand.` You should use `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Because it`Initiates the asynchronous execution of the Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure`... Use `IAsyncResult` and then wait for it to be done if you really want to. [**More information here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2) about it. Also `When the statement has completed, developers must call the EndExecuteNonQuery method to finish the operation.` in which you are *not*...

Comment: Use `ExecuteNonQuery`.